# Three JS: Weird rendering issues in close planes

Tags: javascript, three.js, rendering

I'm using Three.js to render some a few planes with textures, one or top of another.
The distance between the planes is 10 units (which I'm not sure what are these exactly).

All the planes are MeshBasicMaterial, with the following configuration:

```
let frontMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
    map: getFrontCover(),
    side: THREE.FrontSide
});
```

When the planes are placed at the regular distance of 10, I can see strange stripes rendered, like in the picture:

[image]

Assuming that the distance is mandatory, how can I solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: This is called Z clashing or Z fighting. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting There are many ways to solve the problem, . Which to use will depend on your requirements. You have not provided enough info to advice. First step try changing the depth function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/depthFunc There are also 100s of posts on the subject here in SO,

Comment: This isn't a WebGL question it's a three.js question. How to do that in three.js is not answered by any of the webgl related questions.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that!
@gman as three.js is based on WebGL, this is highly relevant to fiddle with the low-level core of this library.

Comment: You miss my point. WebGL answers will reference WebGL solutions. Is this no different then telling someone to read DirectX answers when they asked a OpenGL question. Three.js is its own API and has its own solutions. It's irrelevant that it sometimes uses WebGL.

Comment: Well maybe it's not accurate. I'm just trying to solve the problem, and referring to something outside of the box is really fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you can do.

1. make the near and far settings of your perspective camera as tight fitting to your content as possible.

   For example let's assume the camera is 2 units from the book and the book is 1 unit deep. In that case setting your near and far setting to 0.5 and 3.5 would possibly solve the issue. In other words

   .... new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fieldOfView, aspect, 0.5 /* near */, 3.5 /* far */

   If those numbers are orders of magnitude off you'll get this issue
2. Use a logarithmic depth buffer

   See this example: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=log#webgl_camera_logarithmicdepthbuffer
3. Set the material's polygon offset

   You want to set this on the material for the mesh that is supposed to be behind

   ```
          material.polygonOffset = true;
          material.polygonOffsetFactor = 1;
          material.polygonOffsetUnits = 1;
   ```